# Описание части картинки при нажатии на ее часть

Tags: ajax, php, html

Всем привет.

Есть код вот такой

```
<?php
if ($_GET['id'] == "Bernstein") {
?>
<a id="Bernstein"></a>
<img src="img/stein.png"/>
<?php
} elseif ($_GET['id'] == "Waldstein") {
?>
<img src="img/waldenstein.png"/>
<?php
} elseif ($_GET['id'] == "Brauberg") {
?>
<img src="img/brauberg.png"/>
<?php
} else {
?>
<strong>Безусловным</strong> "королем" строительных материалов, вобравшим в себя природную мощь и красоту, несомненно признаётся натуральный камень.    
<?php
}
?>
```

Принцип таков: на главной стоит картинка дома. Cправа от неё описание.
На картинку наложена мапа <map> и при нажатии на определённую часть дома 
вместо описания появляется картинка с информацией о материале, из которого сделана определенная часть дома! В общем каждый раз, когда методом гет картинка меняется, страница поднимается вверх и колесико нужно крутить вниз! Как связать это с аяксом? Или как сделать, чтобы страница оставалась в прежнем положении?

нашел вот это

```
$.get("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

но как этим пользоваться?

Comment: Почитайте http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: что то я там ничего не понял)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я могу предложить такое решение, но его надо немного дорешать по JavaScript части, ибо в нём, к сожалению, я особо не силён, хотя в данном случае нужно просто знать основы.
В каждом элементе area (карты map) создать обработчик события onclick как атрибут, значением его указать функцию showData().

Примерно так должны выглядеть ваши элементы area:

```
<area shape="poly" coords="113,24,211,24,233,0,137,0" alt="Bernstein" onclick="showData()">
<area shape="poly" coords="113,24,211,24,233,0,137,0" alt="Waldstein" onclick="showData()">
<area shape="poly" coords="113,24,211,24,233,0,137,0" alt="Brauberg" onclick="showData()">
```

Приведённый Вами код вынести в отдельный файл (choice.php, например), файл положить рядом с этой страницей на диске:

```
<?php
// choice.php

if ($_GET['id'] == "Bernstein") {
?>
<a id="Bernstein"></a>
<img src="img/stein.png"/>
<?php
} elseif ($_GET['id'] == "Waldstein") {
?>
<img src="img/waldenstein.png"/>
<?php
} elseif ($_GET['id'] == "Brauberg") {
?>
<img src="img/brauberg.png"/>
<?php
} else {
?>
<strong>Безусловным</strong> "королем" строительных материалов, вобравшим в себя природную мощь и красоту, несомненно признаётся натуральный камень.
<?php
}
?>
```

Следующий код делает асинхронный запрос на choise.php, указываем его в элементе head вашей страницы.

```
<script>
function showData(){
        var stuffName = /* описать код получения alt атрибута, элемента area*/
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", 'choise.php?id=' + stuffName);
        request.send(null);
        request.onreadystatechange = function(response){
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                // выводим полученные данные от выполнения скрипта choise.php в элемент страницы с идентификатором divResult
                document.getElementById("divResult").innerHTML = request.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

В результате в элемент divResult будут вставлены данные полученные из вашего скрипта, страница не будет перезагружаться.
Но вам нужно получить переменную stuffName каким-либо образом :) думаю, что на этом ресурсе помогут.

Answer (score 1):

php не нужен.

Всё делается в рамках одной страницы. Вы выводите сразу html возможных картинок, но прячете их пока. Клики по imagemap обрабатывает JavaScript, заменяя содержание `<div id="info">` на соответствующий `<img src="...">`.

Answer (score -1):

В твоей задаче можно например в гет передавать положение скролинга, и при загрузке страницы если это положение есть, то через JS ставить это положение.

```
    var sH = jQuery(document).scrollTop(); // его передаем

<?php
  if (isset($_GET['sH']))
  {
    // устанавливаем новое положение скролинга
?>
<script>jQuery(document).scrollTop(<?php echo (int)$_GET['sH'];?></script>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: var sH = jQuery(document).scrollTop(); А это мне куда вставлять? я не соображаю в этом нифига! кроме php здесь ничего не понимаю))